# FCM android onmessagereceived not called

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented FCM in the app. Other firebase features working fine i.e. uploading to firebase storage and firebase real time messaging. But when I send push notification 1st time to the device, it shows successfully sent notification, but on messagereceived not called. then immediately when i sent another push notification, it shows not registered. and it always not registered then after.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d("myLog", "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d("myLog", "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
}
```

app.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

project.gralde:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

manifest:

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Device token is refreshed correctly, when ever i clear data and reopen app, it immediately print new device token.

Comment: Show your device register code

Answer (score 1):

**onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)** method called based on the following cases.

- **FCM Response** With **notification** and **data** block:

{
  
"**to**": "device token list",
  "**notification**": {
    "body": "Body of Your Notification",
    "title": "Title of Your Notification"
  },
  "**data**": {
    "body": "Body of Your Notification in Data",
    "title": "Title of Your Notification in Title",
    "key_1": "Value for key_1",
    "image_url": "www.abc.com/xyz.jpeg",
    "key_2": "Value for key_2"
  }
}

1. **App in Foreground:**

**onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)** called,  shows  LargeIcon and BigPicture in the notification bar. We can read the content from both  **notification** and **data** block

2. **App in Background:**

**onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)** not called, system tray will receive the message and read body and title from **notification** block and  shows default message and title in the notification bar.

- **FCM Response** With only **data** block:

In this case, removing **notofocation** blocks from json

{
  
"**to**": "device token list",
  "**data**": {
    "body": "Body of Your Notification in Data",
    "title": "Title of Your Notification in Title",
    "key_1": "Value for key_1",
    "image_url": "www.abc.com/xyz.jpeg",
    "key_2": "Value for key_2"
  }
}

1. **App in Foreground:**

**onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)** called,  shows  LargeIcon and BigPicture in the notification bar. We can read the content from both  **notification** and **data** block

2. **App in Background:**

**onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)** called, system tray will not receive the message because of **notification** key is not in the response. Shows  LargeIcon and BigPicture in the notification bar

**Code**

```
 private void sendNotification(Bitmap bitmap,  String title, String 
    message, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent) {

    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle style = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
    style.bigPicture(bitmap);

    Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = mContext.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "channel_name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
    Bitmap iconLarge = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
            R.drawable.mdmlogo);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mdmlogo)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSound)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setStyle(style)
            .setLargeIcon(iconLarge)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);


    notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());


}
```

**Reference Link:**

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Answer (score 0):

What device are you using for testing this? Some manufacturers like Xiaomi and Leeco are known to prevent apps from receiving FCM notifications.

In case of devices like Samsung, Motorola: Make sure you are handling the right kind of Message type. There are 2 types of FCM messages you can send.

1. Notification Messages
2. Data Messages

Read this page for further information.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: I have checked on most of the devices, moto X play, samsung s6 etc.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

its depend on what type of **Message types** coming from console. 
if its only **Notification messages** then if your app is closed then your receiver will not fired. 
if its with **Notification messages**  and **Data messages**  then still your app can handle this messages when app is in foreground

make sure that you are using this dependency `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'`